# Domain server sync NTP is now 4 mins faster

Tags: ntp

We activated the sync time with external NTP (0.north-america.pool.ntp.org, 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org) on the DC for quite a while, and lately the synchronized time is now abt 4 mins faster than the world time.

Tried to stop / start service and resync NTP commands, but still no help.

And the time synchronization on the hyper v was disabled already earlier, so there should not be interference.

Comment: Can you run `ntpq`, and in that type `rv`, `as`, and `pe` - and cut-and-paste the outputs into your question.

Comment: I'd recommend using three servers, not just two. Otherwise, if one's wrong you have no way to telling which one to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incomplete.

- You forgot `/syncfromflags:manual`.
- You forgot `/reliable:yes` to tell your domain controller the clock is reliable.
- You forgot `/update` to apply the changes to your system.
- Not sure at that point: I would suggest to not use the 0x1 flag as it indicated to use a special poll interval, which is by default 3600 seconds (1 hour). As I understand, it could lead to time differences within the hour, which could lead to problems in Active-Directory. And it could mean, that after an hour, the time jumps for some minutes, when it is adjusted. That would not be too good. Also, this could lead to a phenomenon described here: [When SpecialPollInterval is used as a polling interval, the Windows Time service does not correct the time if the service gets into Spike state](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2638243).

Try this:

`w32tm /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:"0.uk.pool.ntp.org 1.uk.pool.ntp.org 2.uk.pool.ntp.org 3.uk.pool.ntp.org" /reliable:yes /update`

Comment: another side note, [ntp.org](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/use.html) suggests and demonstrates using multiple peers

Comment: i tried researching how w32tm handles a single peer entry, (does it handle it as a pool or only pull a single IP, randomly?) but came up with nothing at the moment. I _assume_ from ntp.org's config that its only grabbing one IP at a time

Comment: @pete In that case w32tm relies on DNS, which resolves the hostname to one IP address using DNS Round Robin IP address selection. My mistake was that I wrongly thought 0.uk.pool.ntp.org would resolve to a specific server, instead resolving in a list of servers.

Answer (score -1):

It is now resolved as the Windows Server NTP commands w32tm was executed wrongly. Command should be:

w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"0.uk.pool.ntp.org,0x1 1.uk.pool.ntp.org,0x1
2.uk.pool.ntp.org,0x1 3.uk.pool.ntp.org,0x1"

Comment: could you specify what you fixed in the command to make it work?